# How to increase the memory of an embedded LDAP server?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm using an embedded LDAP server provided by UnboundID to speed up my unit tests. However, the tests occasionally get hung up because the server runs out of memory. Is there a way to increase the memory of the embedded LDAP server?

Answer (score 0):

The embedded server uses the memory available in your JVM.
You might want to consider giving more memory to your IDE or testsuite process.